# LLVM compile error for a custom back-end

Tags: compilation, llvm, backend

I am getting familiar myself to LLVM, and my goal is to implement a back-end for my custom processor.
Before I jump into my back-end implementation, I first try to learn how a build procedure works, so I first copy lib/Target/MSP430 to lib/Target/myproc, and build llvm targeting "myproc" (even though it actually is a back-end for MSP430, I did this just to learn how I can add a new target to LLVM).

When I configure/make llvm, I got the following error message.

---

...

/bin/cp: cannot stat `/mydir/build/lib/Target/myproc/Debug+Asserts/MSP430GenRegisterInfo.inc.tmp': No such file or directory

...

---

I checked /lib/Target/myproc, and saw there was only one file, Makefile, copied from /lib/Target/myproc.

Here is what I have done before I configure and make.

1. In my LLVM source directory, copy lib/Target/MSP430 to lib/Target/myproc.
2. Modify configure and projects/sample/configure to add "myproc".
3. Go to lib/Target/myproc and change "MSP430" to "myproc" in MSP430.td, LLVMBuild.txt, and Makefile (I also modify the files in subdirectories).

As the LLVM compile works for other targets on my machine, I believe it's not the problem of machine of tools that I am using, but the problem of my modification.

Am I missing something? Are there any further modifications that I am supposed to make?

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent tutorial for writing backends here:

http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html

There's also this tutorial from a dev meeting:

http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-04-12/Slides/Workshops/Anton_Korobeynikov.pdf

*GenRegisterInfo.inc comes from running tblgen on the target .td file.  The .inc output file name depends on what the .td files are named in the myproc/ target directory.

It would be helpful to see more of your make log but my guess is that you're getting a tblgen error when processing .td files in myproc/.  That tblgen error is the real problem you need to diagnose and address.